# How do I use overridden HashCode and Equals on my list?

Tags: java

This is probably a trivial question but I'm having some problems (Probably due to my lack of knowledge and experience and I can't seem to find example code anywhere as I'm not too sure what to search for).

I have a list of Custom objects, `List<StackTrace>`. I want to remove all duplicate objects from this list based only on two properties `firstLineOfStackTrace` and `typeOfException`.

I asked a similar question the other day and someone mentioned about overriding `equals` and `hashCode`. I did a bit of research and I think I have done that now.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((firstLineOfStackTrace == null) ? 0 : firstLineOfStackTrace.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((typeOfexception == null) ? 0 : typeOfexception.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    LogEntry other = (LogEntry) obj;
    if (firstLineOfStackTrace == null) {
        if (other.firstLineOfStackTrace != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!firstLineOfStackTrace.equals(other.firstLineOfStackTrace))
        return false;
    if (typeOfexception == null) {
        if (other.typeOfexception != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!typeOfexception.equals(other.typeOfexception))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

My question is how do I actually use these overridden methods in my code to give me an output which has no duplicates?

Comment: you don't "use them", they are "used" internally in methods like `List::contains`. there are zillions of tutorials online about this

Comment: You can just use a `Set<StackTrace>` like `HashSet` instead of a List. Sets are explicitly made for that purpose (not containing any duplicates and using hashcode/equals internally to detect duplicates)

Comment: I feel that this is a bad case for `equals()` and `hashCode()`. Those methods should refer to the "natural" equality, i.e. what you'd normally expect. If you have a specific use case I'd probably use a `LinkedHashMap`, provide a key class that just contains the properties you want to compare and add the elements to the map. This should get rid of duplicates and maintain the original order as much as possible so if you then build a list of the values in that map you should be good.

Comment: So I can simply just create a new Set with something like `Set<StackTrace> someList = new HashSet<StackTrace>();` and then iterate through my original list and add them to `someList` and duplicates should just not be added ?

Comment: @ConnorGill Yes, or even simpler: HashSet has a constructor that allows you to pass any collection (any List or Set) into it to initialize it. So a simple `Set<Stacktrace> mySet = new HashSet<>(originalList);` is all you need.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS that is exactly what I wanted thank you! I hadn't realized you could just pass a list in like that.

Comment: Just a hint: If you want the `Set` to maintain the element order from the `List`, use a `LinkedHashSet`.